# Como resetear un fork en github?

Tags: github

Resulta que hice un fork de este proyecto 
[Link del Fork Original](https://github.com/DEXdelta/dexdelta.github.io)

El resultado que obtuve fue este
[Link del Fork Resultante del Proceso](https://github.com/cexdelta/cexdelta.github.io)

Pero ahora mismo me gustaria resetear mi proyecto borrar todo y poner todo el contenido del 1 fork en el nuevo que cree? como puedo hacerlo?

Ya que cuando cargo la pagina de mi proyecto presenta algunos problemas que en el 1 no? Como podria por favor resolver este problema si es posible.

Comment: y porque no hacer un nuevo fork si vas a empezar de nuevo?

Comment: a que te refieres con (*resetear*) además de que esa palabra esta mal usada y como programador no me indica nada, que yo sepa en los forks no hay reset, no es una máquina que se encienda y se apague, o se corte la alimentación y se devuelva a estado de encendido al soltar un botón, **Pregunta** consultó usted ya la documentación de **GITHUB** antes de hacer su pregunta aquí ???

Comment: @IgmerRodriguez yo mas bien me pregunto de donde salio eso de resetear un fork ???

Comment: esperen como hago un nuevo fork para evitar perder el anterior como se hace eso?

Comment: no se entiende a qué te refieres con un nuevo fork, porque lo que describes como tu problema, es exactamente la respuesta de tu pregunta, das click en el botón Fork Repository y ya está hecho

Comment: y otro detalle es que no menciona que problemas presenta su nuevo fork, que seguramente no tienen nada que ver con crear un nuevo fork y son completamente relacionados a programación

Answer (score 0):

use el icono de engranaje **(SETTINGS)**
[image: Fork Settings]
Valla al final de las opciones y encontrara esta zona peligrosa **
USTED LA VERÁ EN INGLES** y seleccione la opción que mas se adecue a sus necesidades, creo que no necesita mucha explicación si le el texto de la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Crear nuevo Fork de un Repositorio

de click en el botón fork y siga las instrucciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si pero tenia entendido que se podia borrar todo el repositorio nuevo para devolver como el fork sin borrar o transferir usando un branch o algo asi

Comment: cómo es que entendió eso? en donde lo leyó ? suena confuso y no creo que este cercano a lo que se puede o no puede hacer en github

Comment: un fork y un branch son cosas muy distintas

Comment: tengo entendido que se puede hacer haciendo un merge de un branch puede chekear en los pull request que lo hice de mi repositorio pero el problema esk en pull request pero el boton merge me aparece desactivado y desde consola no se muy bien como usar git

Comment: oh ...!!! ya, ya caigo en lo que quieres hacer, bueno en este momento no puedo complementar la pregunta pero si eres paciente antes de mañana te dejare los pasos a seguir, aunque yo haría lo siguiente, en youtube hay algunos tutoriales para aprender git con github podrías ir viendolos y practicando los conceptos básicos y así cuando te ponga aquí os pasos ya tendrás mucho mayor movilidad en la interface y los comandos git que vas a usar, me encuentro lejos de mi pc y tardare un poco en regresar a ella

Answer (score 0):

Aunque hace mucho de esto, lo dejo por aquí por si alguien lo busca;
en el apartado ABOUT, debajo, pinchar sobre el fork, dentro aparecerá el repo principal y el fork realizado. Pinchar sobre la "copia" y borrar ese repositorio. Al actualizar el fork se ha eliminado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]